# res.redirect, res.sendFile not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, redirect

The res.redirect to 'http://localhost:3000/hello.html' is not working.
I have also tried 'hello.html' instead of 'http://localhost:3000/hello.html'. The hello.html and index2.html files are in the Public folder. I even get the 'in channel1' log on the console. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

```
index.js:

var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var mysql = require("mysql");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "admin123",
  database: "Db"
});
app.use(express.static('./Public'));
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
res.redirect('index2.html');
});

con.connect(function(err){
  if(err){
    console.log('Error connecting to Db');
    return;
  }
  console.log('Connection established');
});

app.get('/channel1', function(req, res) {
    console.log("in channel1");
    res.redirect('http://localhost:3000/hello.html');
});

con.end(function(err) {
  // The connection is terminated gracefully
  // Ensures all previously enqueued queries are still
  // before sending a COM_QUIT packet to the MySQL server.
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("Server is running");
});
```

index2.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
        <script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <h1 align="center">First Page</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <button class ="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block c1" onclick="fun1(1)">1</button>
                </div>
            </div>
</body>
    <script>
        function fun1(num) {
            $.get('/channel1', function() {
                console.log("in channel1");
            });
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Something is probably wrong with your `app.use(express.static('./Public'));` line of code and thus it does not find `hello.html` when the redirected URL request comes in.  Not much we can do here without knowing exactly where everything is located in your file system and how they are relative to the current working directory.  I'm betting that if you put an absolute path into your `express.static()` statement that things will start working.  Then, at that point, you can work on finding the correct relative path if you want a relative path.

Comment: Also, it's a little odd to request `/channel1` in the client with an ajax call and then have the server redirect that to the actual content.  If you're designing both ends, you probably want to just return the desired content when `/channel1` is requested and not do a redirect as that is more efficient and a more straightforward design.